# OpenGL program not reaching main

Tags: c++, opengl, dll, include

I am programming a 3D application in C++ using visual studio 2010, and after testing the code using breakpoints, I have found that the main method isn't being reached. The cmd window is opening, and I believe that the dlls are being loaded, however I am getting the message at the bottom of the output window

> The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x8a8) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
>   The program '[4112] 3dApp_1.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).

If anyone needs more information to help, just let me know, I'm struggling to know what to add without just putting the program up here. Thanks.

edit:
For some reason the program had an issue with a .txt file and a .obj being in the source files directory, so removing that allowed an openGL window to be created.

Comment: How did you determine that the `main` method is never reached? Do you get any kind of error message besides the one you posted? Were there any compiler warnings? You could also try [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) to find out if you're missing any DLLs.

Comment: It was just putting breakpoints in at various points, including the 1st line in main and the main header.

Comment: Without some source code or, in your case, compilation settings it's all just guesswork. Also keep in mind that if you did an optimizing build breakpoints may trigger only delayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the entry point in the settings (see [here](http://progzoo.net/wiki/Creating_a_Glut_project_in_Visual_Studio_2010) or [here](http://www.just.edu.jo/~yaser/courses/cs480/opengl/Using%20OpenGL%20and%20GLUT%20in%20Visual%20Studio.htm)).

Go to Project Properties/Configuration Properties/Linker/Advanced/Entry Point.
Set entry point to mainCRTStartup.

Comment: What do you mean by mainCRTStartup? And I have included the glut files in the right places.

Comment: Did you read the linked pages? Did you follow the menu path I mentioned? Type the string "mainCRTStartup" in the entry point box.

Comment: Yeah, reread the links, and got that working, thanks, although it didn't really solve it.

Comment: You'll have to provide more info on the errors you're getting, and/or post the code somewhere.

Comment: I think I found the issue, which was the way that I was reading in a .txt file, and I was getting stuck in a while(!<ifstream>.eof()), so I just added some text at the end of the file and that solved the issue